# WRT54g router with DD-WRT firmware

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, bridge, wrt54g

I have a WRT54G router with DD-WRT firmware and have it set up as a wireless bridge. Currently it is connected to my main router and then I have a computer in the garage that connects to the WRT54G. In a sense, the WRT54G is my wireless card. I had it laying around and heard that it could do this function.

I want to set up a second computer in the garage - is it possible to use the WRT54G in this way with two computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the first computer plugged into the router (WRT54G)?

If it is plugged into one of the four ports labelled 1 - 4, then yes, you can plug another computer into one of those ports and it should connect and have internet access instantly.

Comment: The first computer is plugged in with a wire. the second computer will be conneceted with a wire as well. but i thought i read somewhere cant find it but that you can only use the client bridge mode on dd-wrt firmware with only one computer. my wrt54g connects wirelessly to my primary router

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx Sorry, by how is it pluged in I meant what port is it (the first computer) connected to? There should be one port labelled 'Internet' and four others labelled from 1 to 4.

Comment: Sorry, i misread your reply. the computer is plugged into port 1 and the second computer into port 2

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx It's OK, I should have worded it better :) Anyway, the ports labelled 1 to 4 are the router ports. That means that the router is sharing the internet connection on all four of those ports. So any computer that you connect to any four of those ports should connect straight away to the internet. Is this what you have tried? Does it work?

Comment: I use DD-WRT with my WRT54G and can confirm that this does indeed work. Utilize any of the 4 ports, as outlined by Connor W, and you can bridge multiple machines.